# Removing a Linux Os completely

Tags: linux, hard-drive, parrot-os

I want to know how to completely remove Linux os from My pc while booting. I Messed up And deleted my */bin* dir by mistake and Nothing works now . I use **Parrot security* Mate 4.xx* . It is the host Operating system and **not** a dual one.

Comment: Just install another OS, not keeping any partitions. Or you are asking about removing a bootloader from the disk?

Comment: I used to have a old Pc which didn't have any OS. Some months ago i installed linux in it. I want to know how to remove Linux .. as it is not usable anymore .(i removed /bin by mistake ) . Will this OS get removed automatically when i Install another Linux with the complete disk space alloted ?

Comment: Yes. Just when it asks if you want to keep current system, answer "no".

Comment: Yeah thanks did it. works perfectly..